# Neural Network ReLU Outputting All 0s

Tags: python, neural-network, gradient-descent, relu

Here is a link to my project: https://github.com/aaronnoyes/neural-network/blob/master/nn.py

I have implemented a basic neural network in python. By default it uses a sigmoid activation function and that works great. I'm trying to compare changes in learning rate between activation functions, so I tried implementing an option for using ReLU. When it runs however, the weights all drop immediately to 0.

```
 if (self.activation == 'relu'):
        d_weights2 = np.dot(self.layer1.T, (2*(self.y - self.output) * self.relu(self.output, True)))
        d_weights1 = np.dot(self.input.T,  (np.dot(2*(self.y - self.output) * self.relu(self.output, True), self.weights2.T) * self.relu(self.layer1, True)))
```

I'm almost sure the issue is in lines 54-56 of my program (shown above) when I try to apply gradient descent. How can I fix this so the program will actually update weights appropriately? My relu implementation is as follows:

```
def relu(self, x, derivative=False):
    if derivative:
        return 1. * (x > 0)
    else:
        return x * (x > 0)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You should always post a [**minimal**, complete, and verifiable exampe](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as you question should be understandable without requiring the reader to follow any links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with your code:

- You are applying a relu to the output layer as well. The recommended standard approach is to use identity as output layer activation for regression and sigmoid/softmax for classification.
- You are using a learning rate of 1, which is way to high. (Usual test values are 1e-2 and smaller.)

I changed the output activation to sigmoid even when using relu activation in the hidden layers

```
def feedforward(self):
   ...

   if (self.activation == 'relu'):
        self.layer1 = self.relu(np.dot(self.input, self.weights1))
        self.output = self.sigmoid(np.dot(self.layer1, self.weights2))

    return self.output

def backprop(self):
    ...

    if (self.activation == 'relu'):
        d_weights2 = np.dot(self.layer1.T, (2*(self.y - self.output) * self.sigmoid(self.output, True)))
        d_weights1 = np.dot(self.input.T,  (np.dot(2*(self.y - self.output) * self.relu(self.output, True), self.weights2.T) * self.relu(self.layer1, True)))
```

and used a smaller learning rate

```
    # update the weights with the derivative (slope) of the loss function
    self.weights1 += .01 * d_weights1
    self.weights2 += .01 * d_weights2
```

and this is the result:

> Actual Output :  [[ 0.00000]  [ 1.00000]  [ 1.00000]  [ 0.00000]]
>
> Predicted Output:  [[ 0.10815]  [ 0.92762]  [ 0.94149]  [ 0.05783]]